# How to convert a NameValueCollection to IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, StringValues>> FormValues?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Can someone explain how I can convert the data in this NameValueCollection to be able to call the function below?

```
string ResponseHash = CalculateHash(Request.Form); // What to do here? Request.Form is a NameValueCollection


private string CalculateHash(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, StringValues>> FormValues)
{

}
```

Comment: Do you know how to loop through a collection? Create instances of KeyValuePairs? Add those to some IEnumerable? Which part of that are you stuck on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use such an extension method:

```
public static class NameValueCollectionExtensions{
    public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, StringValues>> AsEnumerable(this NameValueCollection query)
    {
        return query?.Cast<string>().Select((s, ix) => new KeyValuePair<string, StringValues>(s, query[ix])) 
            ?? Enumerable.Empty<KeyValuePair<string, StringValues>>();
    }
}
```

Now you should be able to use it in this way:

```
string ResponseHash = CalculateHash(Request.Form.AsEnumerable());
```

Additional info: You can use `Cast<string>`  on `NameValueCollection` since it derives from `NameObjectCollectionBase` which in turn has a method [`GetEnumerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.nameobjectcollectionbase.getenumerator?view=net-6.0#system-collections-specialized-nameobjectcollectionbase-getenumerator) that returns the keys as objects(so you need the `Cast`). `Cast<string>` returns `IEnumerable<string>`, the keys.

Comment: Worked! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Helps to realise that `.Cast<string>()` returns an `IEnumerable<string>` populated with the keys

Comment: @bmadtiger: added that information to my answer

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
var nvc = new NameValueCollection();
nvc.Add("key1", "value 1");
nvc.Add("key2", "value 2");
nvc.Add("key3", "value 3");
nvc.Add("key4", "value 4");

var list = nvc.AllKeys.Select(k => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(k, nvc[k]));
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/QRbqmj

Might work